# Can't set search bar with search bar display color iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a "*search bar and search display controller*" `UIObject` added to a `UITableViewController`. The `UITableViewController` itself lies in an embed-linked container view. I am trying to set the color of the "*search bar and search display controller*" using this code in my **UITableViewController.m**'s `viewDidLoad:` method, however it is not working.. what am I doing wrong?

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
self.inviteTableSearchBar.searchBarStyle = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#333333"];
```

**PS** ~   The reason for the two lines is just because I'm trying different things(and these are the only things I could come up with) Also, I've already searched all throughout stack for this question and I'm pretty sure it does not exist.

Comment: I have never seen anything like `...searchBarStyle = [UIColor ...];` there are only 3 possible values...[check: SearchBarStyle Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UISearchBarStyle)

Comment: how many `searchBar`'s do you have? 2? ...`self.searchDisplayController.searchBar` and `self.inviteTableSearchBar` ??

Comment: why not just do `[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];` **as well as** `[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor];`

Comment: These didn't work. Neither did this:      `[self.inviteTableSearchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];`   or this,       `[self.inviteTableSearchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#333333"]];`

Comment: inviteTableSearchBar is my IBOutlet to the "*search bar and search bar display view controller*", if you're confused as to what this "search bar and search display controller" UIObject is, check the UIObjects tab in IB, it's right next to the "search bar"

Comment: post a pic of your current layout and also double check that the `searchBarStyle` is `UISearchBarStyleDefault` and **not** `UISearchBarStyleMinimal`

Comment: I figured it out, but thank you. I just used this:     `[self.inviteTableSearchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];`
and then set the color with     `self.inviteTableSearchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#333333"];`

Comment: great... post your solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Found:**

I used this method to reset/recreate the background:

```
[self.inviteTableSearchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Then simply reset my background UIColor using:

```
self.inviteTableSearchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#333333"];
```

No need to re-instantiate your`UISearchBar`'s subclass.